# Accessing Adventure Worlds in Lego Dimensions

Tags: xbox-one, lego-dimensions

How do you get to the adventure world portals after this last update? The elevator no longer works, the level select on the main menu is disabled, and when I use the little console beside the portal, all of the worlds show up as question marks on both Vorton and the Shard. The characters that I've bought that have level packs do unlock the level, but not the adventure world, and the characters that don't have their own levels (Jurassic World, for example) don't appear to do anything at all. I'm certain everything has been downloaded, but there's just no way to access the worlds.

Answer (score 1):

This [GameFAQs thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/144673-lego-dimensions/72917086) or this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Legodimensions/comments/3z8lv4/cant_access_elevator_levels_in_vorton_world/) may hold helpful answers for you.

The two big suggestions seem to be:

1. Uninstall and reinstall all of the DLC for the game. I would add uninstalling and reinstalling the game as well, just in case that would help.
2. Use a flying character to access the upper levels. Either via the elevator shaft or by going to the end of the main hub and flying upwards.